# How to open activity via notification to chat screen?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am creating chatting application using firebase in android studio, my all activity working properly expect my open activity via notification.
my applications shows the notifications but when I click to the notification my app becomes crash

here is MyFirebaseMessaging.java

```
package com.example.registration.notifications;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.example.registration.chatscreen;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull @NotNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        String sendted=remoteMessage.getData().get("sented");
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(firebaseUser !=null && sendted.equals(firebaseUser.getUid()))
        {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                sendOreoNotification(remoteMessage);
            }
            else{
                sendnotification(remoteMessage);
            }
        }   }
    private void sendOreoNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String user=remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
        String icon=remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
        String title=remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body=remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification= remoteMessage.getNotification();
        int j =Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]",""));
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, chatscreen.class);
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("userid",user);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent  pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(this,j,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        OreoNotification oreoNotification=new OreoNotification(this);
        Notification.Builder builder=oreoNotification.getOreoNotification(title,body,pendingIntent,defaultSound,icon);
        int i=0;
        if(j>0){
            i=j;
        }
        oreoNotification.getManger().notify(i, builder.build());
    }
    private void sendnotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

            String user=remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
            String icon=remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
            String title=remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            String body=remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification= remoteMessage.getNotification();
        int j =Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]",""));
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, chatscreen.class);
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("userid",user);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent  pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(this,j,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Notification.Builder builder=new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(Integer.parseInt(icon))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager noti=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int i=0;
        if(j>0){
            i=j;
        }
        noti.notify(i, builder.build());
    }
}
```

and here OreoNotification.java

```
package com.example.registration.notifications;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
public class OreoNotification extends ContextWrapper {
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID="com.example.registration";
    private static final String CHANNEL_NAME="registration";
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    public OreoNotification(Context base) {
        super(base);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            cretechannel();
        }
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void cretechannel() {
        NotificationChannel channel=new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,CHANNEL_NAME,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.enableLights(false);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        getManger().createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    public NotificationManager getManger(){
        if (notificationManager==null){
            notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
        return notificationManager;
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public Notification.Builder getOreoNotification(String title, String body, PendingIntent pendingIntent, Uri soundUri,String icon){
        return  new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(),CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setSmallIcon(Integer.parseInt(icon))
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
    }}
```

anyone knows how to fix this ??

Comment: What is the error, and can you share your chatscreen class code?

Comment: when I click on Notification for open the activity directly via notification my app become crash ! , I wanted to direct open my activity when I click the notification

Comment: The error as in the stack trace printed after it crashes